# Former ManytoMany object is not added

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to add a new passenger to the flight, and I use models to store that. But instead, it had absolutely no change after I submit the form, except for the unexpected URL change: from **localhost:8000/flights/5** to **localhost:8000/flights/5/book**
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62N8g.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrtiw.png)

```
def book(request, flight_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
        passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST["passenger"]))
        passenger.flights.add(flight)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight", args=(flight.id,)))
```

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    flights = models.ManyToManyField(Flight, blank=True, related_name="passengers")
```

Flight is another class, by the way.
And there are my urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>", views.flight, name="flight"),
    path("<int:flight_id>/book", views.flight, name="book")
]
```

any idea why it's going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe because you called views.flight rather than views.book in the booking one?

Comment: @SantiagoIvulich Thanks for your kind answer!!!! I try to find this bug for nearly 4 hours!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the `urlpatterns` to include the views.book:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:flight_id>", views.flight, name="flight"),
    path("<int:flight_id>/book", views.book, name="book")
]
```